# Чтение цвета из Bitmap, полученного с помощью DirectX

Tags: delphi, bitmap, directx, delphi-xe3

Есть задача прочитать цвет пикселя из файла `BMP`, который помещен в `image1`. Надо использовать для чтения файла `TMemoryStream`, так как воспользоваться `image1.Canvas.Pixels[x,y]` нет возможности - "пипетка" отключается когда запущено `DirectX` приложение, а оно запущено и из него это `BMP` и берется в виде скриншота.

**Дополнение!!!**

Оказалось что - взятие цвета `Bitmap.Pixels` начало работать раз через раз. В чем может быть проблема? В общем: компилирую приложение, запускаю от `имена админа` - `PostMessage` не работает, цвет возвращает нули. Закрываю приложение. Запускаю по новой - и то и то работает. И так все время. Раньше такое же поведение заметил в модуле `TICQ` - раз через раз при запусках не хотело логиниться. Что это может быть? Как видно - я **не редактирую код между запусками**, и даже **не компилирую**. **Просто перезапускаю** и либо все работает либо все не работает. У меня `Delphi XE3` и `Win10`.

И так. **Не всегда** работают участки кода (Запускаю от `имени админа`), но иногда работают при **многократном перезапуске** приложения:

```
procedure TForm1.F10Timer(Sender: TObject);
var wnd: HWND;
begin
wnd:=FindWindow(0, 'Lineage II'); //находим окно
if (wnd<>0) then //если найдено то выполняем код (находит всегда)
begin
  PostMessage(wnd,WM_KEYDOWN, VK_f10,0); //нажимаем F10
  label14.Caption:='F10'; //для себя пишем на форме что клавиша нажата
end;
end;
```

Таких процедур много, они идентичны, и все вместе либо работают либо нет. В них собственно посылается нажатие клавиш в окно игры (да, я пишу бота).

Далее - определение цвета. Работает только если работает отправка нажатий клавиш (имею ввиду вот этот баг, что описан мною выше):

```
procedure TForm2.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var GetSc:Dx.TImageCatcher;
begin
GetSc:=Dx.TImageCatcher.Create; //создаю экземпляр класса (Dx.pas)
GetSc.TargetHandle:=FindWindow(0, 'Lineage II'); //передаю заголовок игры
GetSc.CatchType:=ctDirectX; //установил способ съемки
GetSc.ActivateTarget; //активирую окно игры
GetSc.GetScreenShot; //это битмап, сюда грузим снимок
image1.Picture.Bitmap:=GetSc.Bitmap; //из битмапа передаем снимок в image1
image1.canvas.CopyRect(image1.ClientRect,image1.Canvas,rect(27,58,181,95)); //оставляю в image1 только интересующую меня область (шкала CP, HP, MP)
image1.Picture.bitmap.width:=155; //ровняем размеры
image1.Picture.bitmap.Height:=38; //ровняем размеры
image1.Picture.Bitmap.Dormant; //переводим image1 по совету из камментов
labelededit1.Text:=inttohex(image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[135,19],6); //пробуем узнать цвет
end;
```

Фактически тут весь пример, все остальное аналогичное. Есть мнение что либо компилятор грешит, либо WinAPI, понять не могу. Это все **иногда** шикарно работает, если уж начало работать, а результат вот он:

Ссылка на окно: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3g0HJYW_bzHcnNHWEtTMDVxdXc

Lineage II в списке окон. Окно "Lineage II" класс "L2UnrealWWindowsViewportWindow". Дочерних как видим нет.

Ссылка: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g0HJYW_bzHNU1LX3lqWDlfZ2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Дополнение: при запущенном приложении `DirectX` взятие цвета пикселя из точки экрана или из `image1` вышеописанным методом возвращает код цвета `000000` в `hex`.

Comment: А само-то изображение в image появляется? Вы не показали код, которым заносится картинка в image. Попробуйте сделать `image1.Picture.Bitmap.Dormant` - это преобразует битмап в DIB, а после этого получить доступ через `image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels`. Работать с бинарным содержимым битмапа - неблагодарное занятие. Расположение байт конкретного пикселя зависит от разрядности битмапа и других факторов.

Comment: Вот так с помощью метода из другого юнита загружаю в `image`: `image1.Picture.Graphic:=GetSc.Bitmap;` Изображение показывается нормально. `GetSc.Bitmap` это метод из юнита, которым я при помощи `DirectX` вытаскиваю изображение из `Z-буфера` игры. Сейчас попробую ваш совет и отпишусь! Спасибо!

Comment: Когда игра не запущена - работает на ура. Когда же запущена - скрин делает, `Dormant` выполняю, но вместо цвета в итоге `000000`. Уже всю голову сломал, даже не могу представить что делать с этим и почему так.

Comment: Вот скриншот https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g0HJYW_bzHcnNHWEtTMDVxdXc/view?usp=sharing
Там где полоска `HP` я пытаюсь получить цвет точки. Эти два рисунка прилетают в `image1` и `image2` из `DirectX`. Как видно в `LabeledEdit` "Цвет HP" - вместо цвета нули. Закрываю игру и пробую скринить любое другое окно - цвет правильный.

Comment: Похоже, что вы решаете проблему удаления аппендицита через ухо. Добавьте в начало описание основной проблемы (узнать цвет пикселя в игре или .. ?).

Comment: Да, основная проблема и есть узнать цвет пикселя в окне `DirectX`. Делал снимок окна (не `HDC` методами), загружаю его в `image1`. `Pixels` не работает. Вот и ищу как прочитать цвет

Comment: Изменил суть вопроса

Comment: Покажите уже нам свой код. Где у вас срабатывает через раз?

Comment: Добавил код в описание. Возможно кроме запуска от имени админа нужно еще какие-то права дать дополнительно?

Comment: Хм, разве не очевидно, что по какой-то причине не находится окно? Напишите процедуру собирающую все окна "верхнего уровня" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) и выведите их куда-нибудь с указанием названий классов и заголовков. Потом будем разбираться, почему 'Lineage II' не нашлось.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, с Delphi-евскими формами всегда была проблема, что они являются не "top-level" окнами, а детьми спрятаного окна Application.

Comment: Есть у меня уже такое. Скриншот добавлю сейчас в описание. И бот отлично видит окно Lineage

Comment: Окно всегда находится, так как если посмотрите код с условием нажатия F10, то сможете увидеть, что я кроме отправки нажатия еще меняю текст `label14.Caption:='F10';` и меняется он всегда, что есть доказательством того что все сработало, но...

Comment: Что такое `Dx.pas` и `TImageCatcher`? Это не стандартный модуль. Свойство `TImageCatcher.Bitmap` имеет тип `Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
GetSc := Dx.TImageCatcher.Create; //создаю экземпляр класса (Dx.pas)
try
  GetSc.TargetHandle := FindWindow(0, 'Lineage II'); //передаю заголовок игры
  GetSc.CatchType := ctDirectX; //установил способ съемки
  GetSc.ActivateTarget; //активирую окно игры
  GetSc.GetScreenShot; //это битмап, сюда грузим снимок
  image1.Picture.Bitmap := GetSc.Bitmap; //из битмапа передаем снимок в image1
finally
  GetSc.Free;
end;

image1.ScanLine(0); // дальше можно работать с указателем на массив пикселей, полученным от функции ScanLine или делать как раньше   

image1.canvas.CopyRect(image1.ClientRect,image1.Canvas, rect(27,58,181,95)); //оставляю в image1 только интересующую меня область (шкала CP, HP, MP)
image1.Picture.bitmap.width:=155; //ровняем размеры
image1.Picture.bitmap.Height:=38; //ровняем размеры
labelededit1.Text:=inttohex(image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[135,19], 6); //пробуем узнать цвет
```

Comment: Спасибо за Вашу помощь! Я добавил ваши правки, но к сожалению это никак не повлияло на ситуацию. Сегодня с раза 20го заставил это все работать =(
P.S.: в смысле раз 20 перезапускал приложение пока не заработало

Comment: Сейчас ставлю 10 Seattle, есть мнение что моя версия XE3 грешит

Comment: Увы и ах! Установил новый Делфи, удалил скомпиленный файл, скомпилил заново в 10 Seattle и... ничего. Опять игнор

Comment: А если сделать `GetSc.Bitmap.SaveToFile('ScreenShot.bmp');` после `GetSc.GetScreenShot;` файл всегда будет выглядеть адекватно?

Comment: Я бы сказал- адекватнее некуда. Очень хорошо сохраняет. Поэтому и дошел до того что надо пробовать цвет в hex брать из файла.

Comment: Переделал код в ответе. Добавил вызов `image1.ScanLine(0);`, который выполняет те же подготовительные действия, что и `SaveToFile` перед сохранением. Так должно работать без сохранения в файл.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваше время! Я сейчас на парах, как буду дома- проверю и отпишу. Еще раз спасибо